# The Window > Animator apply for all players how i can make it to apply only for some of the players?

Tags: c#, unityscript, unity-game-engine

I created in the Window > Animator a new empty state called it Walk using HumandoidWalk and set it as default when running the game all the 3 ThirdPersonControllers start walking automatic. How can i make that the main player will not walk automatic and will be controlled only by the user ?

The two guards are patrolling so i want them to start walking automatic when running the game. But the Main Player should not be walking automatic. The problem is that the Walk state in the Animator is applying for all the characters.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You can set the animation for every agent/player in each script. The player would update the animator via input.

Answer (score 0):

You can duplicate the animator and change the default state for any of the states you want. Then put it on player animator component. Right click on any state ans set as default to change default state.

For player you will need a transaction between the default state and walk state as well as code input.